# apply k-Nearest Neighbors in dataset in python

Tags: python

I have a dataset in CSV file and all data is a numeric attribute, I want to apply k-Nearest Neighbors in my dataset

I have some error in my code I don't know who I can fix it.

code:
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your code and error as text instead of images.

Comment: I would highly recommend numpy. Pure python is slow.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the `instance1[x]` and `instance2[x]` where you are applying subtraction is a `string` type.
You cannot subtract 2 strings, so you can modify your code like,

```
distance += pow( ( int(instance1[x])-int(instance2[x]) ),2)
```

This will read the variable as `int` type, thus you can subtract it.

you can replace `int` with `float` `double` etc also

Comment: remove the space between `iteritems` and `()` in `sortedVotes`.its buit-in-function.

Comment: The code needed is `sortedVotes = sorted ( classVotes.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter ( 1 ), reverse=True )`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line defining variable `sortedVotes` with

```
sortedVotes = sorted ( classVotes.items(), key=operator.itemgetter ( 1 ), reverse=True )
```

Comment: if you are using python 3 `items()` is required....`iteritems()` in no more in python3

Comment: `sortedVotes = sorted ( classVotes.items(), key=operator.itemgetter ( 1 ), reverse=True )`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

class knn:

    def __init__ (self, x, y, k):
        self.k = k
        self.x_data = x 
        self.y_data = y

    def predict(self, test):
        dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((self.x_data-test)**2,axis=1))
        closest = np.argpartition(dist, self.k)[0:self.k]
        a,b = np.unique(self.y_data[closest],return_counts=True)
        return a[np.where(b == b.max())]
```

x: features, y: label, k: number of neighbors

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a numpy only function that will work

Where `d` is a numpy array of datapoints with shape (n_datapoints, n_features).

And `q` is a numpy array of query points with shape (n_queries, n_features).

and `K` is the number of neighbors you wish to get back.

n_features refers to the number of dimensions in your data.

```
def calc_k_nearest_neighbors(d, q, K=1):
    return d[((d[None, :, :] - q[:, None, :]) ** 2).sum(axis=2).argsort()[:,:K]]
```

There are some complicated python concepts going on in here, so if you wish to learn more, look into array broadcasting, np.argsort, and views of arrays.